# Spring Batch - Processing Large Amounts of Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am looking for a strategy to process a large amount of records with spring batch. The reader takes one line as input, the processor can generate a list of items of a size so big that they can't fit in memory. The flow is essentially: 
read -> generate -> write

Not sure if some sort of nested batching is the way to go, maybe using a tasklet, or if I am holding spring batch wrong in general.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pre-generate the list in a separate step in a way that works?  Staging table, etc?

Comment: What I was thinking was doing something like

Read request -> Have some provider that provides 500k generated rows at a time -> writer that writes them as such.

The problem is how do I do that? I need some kind of item processor that can keep continually returning data to the writer in chunks so I don't blow up the heap.

Comment: I'd create a reader that does the generation as well.  Reader gets the input, then provides chunks of the generated content as an item.  The rest of the step works accordingly.

Comment: Hey mike, that's an excellent idea. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you need to implement a custom Reader/Generator/Writer with Reader state - e.g. Pageable so instead of generating list of items you generate list of "pages". Each page contains a reference to original line from the file and page info [offset, page size].

Generator in turn converts the "source pages" to relatively small containers with items.